# How to add delete button whose should delete in site and json file

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

I'm newbie in javascript and I need help. In code i need to add two delete button:

1. delete one object created
2. delete all objects created

This buttons need to delete object in a json file. I don't know how to write the function, please help!
The code is created in html, javascript and php, and send by ajax.
Objects must be deleted in the site, too.

```js
function checkInputText(value, msg) {
    if (value == null || value == "") {
        alert(msg);
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}        
function Todo(index, part, pieces, weight) {
    this.index = index;
    this.part = part;
    this.pieces = pieces;
    this.weight = weight;
}
                      
var todos = new Array();

window.onload = init;

function init() {
    var submitButton = document.getElementById("submit");
    submitButton.onclick = getFormData;
    getTodoData();
}

function getTodoData() {
    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    request.open("GET", "todo.json");
    request.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (this.readyState == this.DONE && this.status == 200) {
            if (this.responseText) { 
                parseTodoItems(this.responseText);
                addTodosToPage();
            }
            else {
                console.log("error");
            }
        }
    };
    request.send();
}

function parseTodoItems(todoJSON) {
    if (todoJSON == null || todoJSON.trim() == "") {
        return;
    }
    var todoArray = JSON.parse(todoJSON);
    if (todoArray.length == 0) {
        console.log("Error: the to-do list array is empty!");
        return;
    }
    for (var i = 0; i < todoArray.length; i++) {
        var todoItem = todoArray[i];
        todos.push(todoItem);
        addTodosToPage(todoItem);
    }
}

function addTodosToPage() {
  var table = document.getElementById("todoList");
  var tr = document.createElement("tr");
  var index = document.getElementById('index').value;
  var part = document.getElementById('part').value;
  var pieces = document.getElementById('pieces').value;
  var weight = document.getElementById('weight').value;
  tr.innerHTML = "<td>" + index + "</td><td>" + part + "</td><td>" + pieces + "</td><td>" + weight + "<td>";
  table.appendChild(tr);
}
function checkInputText(value, msg) {
    if (value == null || value == "") {
        alert(msg);
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}        

function saveTodoData() {
    var todoJSON = JSON.stringify(todos);
    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var URL = "save.php?data=" + encodeURI(todoJSON);
    request.open("GET", URL);
    request.setRequestHeader("Content-Type",
                             "text/plain;charset=UTF-8");
    request.send();
}
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Index</th>
      <th>Part</th>
      <th>Pieces</th>
      <th>Weight</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody id="todoList">
  </tbody>
</table>

<form>
  <fieldset>
    <div class="tableContainer">
      <label for="index">
        <select id="index" name="index"> 
          <option hidden="" >Index</option> 
          <option value="1">1</option>
          <option value="2">2</option>
          <option value="3">3</option>
          <option value="5">5</option>
          <option value="6">6</option>
          <option value="7">7</option>
          <option value="8">8</option>
          <option value="9">9</option>
          <option value="10">10</option>
        </select>
      </label>
      <input placeholder="part" id="part" />
      <input placeholder="pieces" id="pieces" />
      <input placeholder="weight" id="weight" />
      <input type="button" id="submit" value="ADD" onclick="addTodosToPage()">
    </div>
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

```
<?php 

if (function_exists('get_magic_quotes_gpc') && get_magic_quotes_gpc()) { 
    function strip_slashes($input) {
        if (!is_array($input)) { 
            return stripslashes($input); 
        } else { 
            return array_map('strip_slashes', $input); 
        } 
    } 
    $_GET = strip_slashes($_GET); 
    $_POST = strip_slashes($_POST); 
    $_COOKIE = strip_slashes($_COOKIE); 
    $_REQUEST = strip_slashes($_REQUEST); 
} 
function customError($errno, $errstr) { 
    echo "<b>Error:</b> [$errno] $errstr<br>"; 
    echo "Ending Script"; 
    die("Ending Script"); 
} 
set_error_handler("customError"); 
$myData = $_GET["data"]; 
$myFile = "todo.json"; 
$fileHandle = fopen($myFile, "w"); 
fwrite($fileHandle, $myData); 
fclose($fileHandle); 

?>
```

Comment: Basically you will have 2 commands performed by the PHP script - create an empty JSON file to delete all objects, or read the file + `json_decode()` to parse it, then delete the corresponding object, then serialize the list with `json_encode()` and save the result, overwriting the existing JSON file.

Answer (score 0):

Before I start, I'm going on a bit of a paranoid tangent and stress that the server-side PHP code you're using is not secure. For one, **[PHP magic quotes are deprecated and should be avoided](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.whynot.php)** and two, preparing the data client-side and then saving it to the server without question is a *very bad idea*.

**Never trust the client** to format the data, otherwise I can come along and do this:

```
    var myOwnJson = [{ "data": [{
      "index":"<script>alert('You');<\/script>",
      "part":"<script>alert('Are');<\/script>",
      "pieces":"<script>alert('Not');<\/script>",
      "weight":"<script>alert('Safe');<\/script>"
      }] }];
    var URL = "save.php?data=" + encodeURI(JSON.stringify(myOwnJson));
```

[I'd recommend reading about input sanitization and validation.](https://www.wordfence.com/learn/how-to-write-secure-php-code/) You can still build a JSON file on the client and submit it to the server but the server needs to make sure it's checking the input is as expected.

As an example:

```
<?php 
// Try to parse read the json file as an associative array.
$unsafe_json = json_decode( $_GET["data"], true );

if( ! is_array( $unsafe_json ) ) {
    // Otherwise die, and tell the user.
    die('Failed to save');
}

// Start building a trusted json array.
$safe_json = [ 'data' => [] ];

// These are the only keys we'll accept for each todo item.
$values = [ 'index', 'part', 'pieces', 'weight' ];

foreach( $unsafe_json as $unsafe_todo ) {
    $safe_todo = [];

    foreach( $values as $value ) {
        if( isset( $unsafe_todo[$value] ) && is_string( $unsafe_todo[$value] ) ) {
            // Sanitize the value from the submitted json array.
            $safe_todo[$value] = filter_var( $unsafe_todo[$value], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING );
        } else {
            // This value wasn't found in the array, we'll mark it as false.
            $safe_todo[$value] = false;
        }
    }

    // Add our validated todo item to the list.
    $safe_json['data'][] = $safe_todo;
}

// Save the file
$file = fopen( "todo.json", "w" ); 
fwrite( $file, '[' . json_encode( $safe_json ) . ']' ); 
fclose( $file );
```

I'm *sanitizing* the submitted data and removing unwanted code while *validating* that the submitted data is formatted the way I expect it to be.

Going a step further, I could validate that `index` and `weight` are numeric values using `FILTER_VALIDATE_INT` or `is_numeric` *which I could then whinge to the user about.* Or I could sanitize those values with `FILTER_SANITIZE_INT` or `intval` to make sure those values are in a format I expect.

---

**But enough of the security naggage... I'll actually answer your question now.**

Without making too many changes to your current code, one way you can add a delete button or multiple delete button would be using a checkbox column. I've marked these changes in the code below, but to summarise:

- Give each row an index and id so they can be quickly identified. Eg. `<tr id="row-1"></tr>`
- *I've done this by creating a global count of how many todo items there are.*
- In each row, add a checkbox, give it the value of the row's index.
- Make a function that deletes a row based on an index parameter. Eg. `removeTodo(1);`
- Make a function that loops through selected checkboxes and issue the `removeTodo()` function using their value.
- Link those functions to buttons.

```js
// 1 ) Add a global variable to count the todo items we have.
var todo_index = 0;

function checkInputText(value, msg) {
  if (value == null || value == "") {
    alert(msg);
    return true;
  }
  return false;
}

function Todo(index, part, pieces, weight) {
  this.index = index;
  this.part = part;
  this.pieces = pieces;
  this.weight = weight;
}

var todos = new Array();

window.onload = init;

function init() {
  var submitButton = document.getElementById("submit");
  //submitButton.onclick = getTodoData;
  //getTodoData();
}

function getTodoData() {
  var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
  request.open("GET", "todo.json");
  request.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == this.DONE && this.status == 200) {
      if (this.responseText) {
        parseTodoItems(this.responseText);
        addTodosToPage();
      } else {
        console.log("error");
      }
    }
  };
  request.send();
}

function parseTodoItems(todoJSON) {
  if (todoJSON == null || todoJSON.trim() == "") {
    return;
  }
  var todoArray = JSON.parse(todoJSON);
  if (todoArray.length == 0) {
    console.log("Error: the to-do list array is empty!");
    return;
  }
  for (var i = 0; i < todoArray.length; i++) {
    var todoItem = todoArray[i];
    todos.push(todoItem);
    addTodosToPage(todoItem);
  }
}

function addTodosToPage() {
  var table = document.getElementById("todoList");
  var tr = document.createElement("tr");

  // 2 ) Increment the number of todos we have by 1.
  todo_index++;

  // 3 ) Set the row ID to an index.
  tr.id = "todo-" + todo_index;

  var index = document.getElementById('index').value;
  var part = document.getElementById('part').value;
  var pieces = document.getElementById('pieces').value;
  var weight = document.getElementById('weight').value;

  // 4 ) Add a checkbox for selecting the row and a remove button for removing the row.
  tr.innerHTML = "\
  <td><input name='select-row' type='checkbox' value='" + todo_index + "'></td>\
  <td>" + index + "</td>\
  <td>" + part + "</td>\
  <td>" + pieces + "</td>\
  <td>" + weight + "</td>\
  <td><button onclick='removeTodo(" + todo_index + ");'>x</button><td>";
  table.appendChild(tr);
}

function checkInputText(value, msg) {
  if (value == null || value == "") {
    alert(msg);
    return true;
  }
  return false;
}

function saveTodoData() {
  var todoJSON = JSON.stringify(todos);
  var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
  var URL = "save.php?data=" + encodeURI(todoJSON);
  request.open("GET", URL);
  request.setRequestHeader("Content-Type",
    "text/plain;charset=UTF-8");
  request.send();
}

// 5 ) Add a function which will remove a todo item based on it's index.
function removeTodo(index) {
  // Get the element.
  var row = document.getElementById('todo-' + index);

  // If we were able to find a row matching that id.
  if (row) {
    // Access row's parent node (tbody) and remove the row.
    row.parentNode.removeChild(row);
  }

  // Decrement the todo count by 1.
  todo_index--;
}

// 6 ) Add a function so we can click 'select all' to either select all rows or deselect all rows.
function toggleSelection(checkbox) {
  // Get our rows.
  var rowsToSelect = document.querySelectorAll('input[name=select-row]');

  for (var i = 0; i < rowsToSelect.length; i++) {
    // Check or uncheck boxes if the 'master' checkbox is checked.
    rowsToSelect[i].checked = checkbox.checked;
  }
}

// 7 ) Add a function to remove all rows that are selected.
function removeSelectedTodos() {
  // Get our rows.
  var rowsToRemove = document.querySelectorAll('input[name=select-row]:checked');

  for (var i = 0; i < rowsToRemove.length; i++) {
    // Delete the row.
    removeTodo(rowsToRemove[i].value);
  }
}
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <!-- 8 ) Add a 'select all' checkbox. -->
      <th><input onchange="toggleSelection(this);" type='checkbox'></th>
      <th>Index</th>
      <th>Part</th>
      <th>Pieces</th>
      <th>Weight</th>
      <!-- 9 ) Add a 'delete selected' button -->
      <th><button onclick='removeSelectedTodos();'>x</button></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody id="todoList">
  </tbody>
</table>

<form>
  <fieldset>
    <div class="tableContainer">
      <label for="index">
        <select id="index" name="index"> 
          <option hidden="" >Index</option> 
          <option value="1">1</option>
          <option value="2">2</option>
          <option value="3">3</option>
          <option value="5">5</option>
          <option value="6">6</option>
          <option value="7">7</option>
          <option value="8">8</option>
          <option value="9">9</option>
          <option value="10">10</option>
        </select>
      </label>
      <input placeholder="part" id="part" />
      <input placeholder="pieces" id="pieces" />
      <input placeholder="weight" id="weight" />
      <input type="button" id="submit" value="ADD" onclick="addTodosToPage()">
    </div>
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

As for updating the todo list on the server: your current code is already on track to do that. If you submit the values to the server and it saves them into a json file that overwrites the old one, you've updated the server's version of the todo list.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks! But now, when i add new postion this isn't save in todo.json. Do you know why?

Comment: @Despo To do that you'll need to add the todo item to your `todos` array when pressing the add button and call the `saveTodoData()` function. The focus of the JavaScript I provided was on adding/removing items.

Comment: could you please show where i should do this? I see you delete all getFormData() where is the saveTodoData() but when i add all this function or just:  addTodosToPage(todoItem);
    saveTodoData(); nothing is happend

Comment: Please, could you help me?

Comment: Ok i got it, now i still can't remove object from json file.